# jQuery button click handler not executing

Tags: jquery

I have button in a form

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-reset-mainform">Reset</button>
```

This button's click event is handled in a separate .js file so that i can use the following code in other form also. But it is not executing.

```
$('#btn-reset-mainform').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    ResetMainForm(form);
});
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: whether the script is within a dom ready handler

Comment: @SKPaul is the button loaded dynamically ?

Comment: @ open console and see error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#btn-reset-mainform',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        ResetMainForm(form);
    });
})
```

**NOTE** : Add your js file after jquery file.

Comment: Dear rajesh, your suggestion is perfectly working. Thanks. +1.

Answer (score 1):

write your code in **[document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** and **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//^^^^^^^add this in your script
$(document).on("click","#btn-reset-mainform",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('resettng from lib');

    var form = $(this).parents('form');
    ResetMainForm(form); alert('resettng from lib');
    });

});
```

Comment: @Riturajratan Add your js file after jquery file

Comment: your button make dynamic then use on

Comment: @ratan, thanks for your effort. I'm going to +1 you.